# How to prevent onselectionchanged method in aggrid to stop executing multiple times?

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I am using aggrid, where i have onselectionchanged method. So if I select 7k rows, it is executing 7000 times which causing page to hang.

If Anybody knows the reason it is that executing multiple times please share. How can I prevent this.

```js
function onSelectionChanged() {

    getSelectedRowToStore();
}

function getSelectedRowToStore() {
    var myRowStorage = document.getElementById('recordJsonStore');
    // Convert the JSON String into an Object so we can manipulate it

    if (myRowStorage != null && myRowStorage != '') {
        dataSampleAfterUpdate = JSON.parse(myRowStorage.getAttribute('data-rows'));

    }
    if (dataSampleAfterUpdate == null) {
        dataSampleAfterUpdate = [];
    }


    var selectedRows = gridOptions.api.getSelectedRows(); //Here I am getting 7k on first time.But it again excecutes
    var obj = Object.fromEntries(dataSampleAfterUpdate.map(e => [e.Id, e]));

    selectedRows.forEach(function(selectedRow, index) {
        obj[selectedRow.Id] = selectedRow;
    });

    dataSampleAfterUpdate = Object.values(obj);

    var myRowStorage = document.getElementById('recordJsonStore');
    myRowStorage.setAttribute('data-rows', JSON.stringify(dataSampleAfterUpdate));
    if (dataSampleAfterUpdate.length > 0) {
        document.getElementById("unsavedLabel").style.display = 'inline-block';
        document.getElementById("unsaved").innerHTML = dataSampleAfterUpdate.length;
    }
}

var gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    rowData: arr1,
    checkbox: true,
    rowSelection: 'multiple',
    suppressRowClickSelection: true,
    rowMultiSelectWithClick: true,
    onSelectionChanged: onSelectionChanged,
    suppressCopyRowsToClipboard: true,
    animateRows: true,
    defaultColDef: {
        resizable: true,
        sortable: true
    },
    enterMovesDown: true,
    enterMovesDownAfterEdit: true,
    //rowBuffer: 500,
    enableRangeSelection: true
}
```

Comment: how are you selecting multiple rows? using CTRL and Shift? the `onSelectionChanged` function will only be called once even if you select multiple rows. See [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/2SiUczTe07lfQ48p) plunker (look at the console logs).

Comment: I am using a custom function  to select multiple rows using shortcut ctrl+space(like ms Excel). So once it is selected, If i do ctrl+v it is executing multiple time, because row selection event is being called for multiple times

Comment: you need to post to the complete code in order to reproduce the issue

Comment: Please have a look at these https://plnkr.co/edit/wxvsGulAtiD4B91g?preview

Comment: In this plunker we cant reproduce but selection is happening

Answer (score 0):

the thing you are experiencing is normal. Since you are using a custom function, you must be looping over the rows and setting them to selected. something like this :

```
this.gridApi.forEachNode(node => {
   node.setSelected(true); // or false for that matter
});
```

for each node set to selected, the event `onSelectionChanged` will trigger.

Sadly, I don't think there is any other way to do this, as the infinite mode on agGrid seems to have this limitation and doesn't seem to have any hope for fixing. So you need to work around it, by trying to accumulate the `onSelectionChanged` event calls in some way.

Comment: This took me forever to find, but if you look at the docs there is actually two other arguments to node.setSelected. The third argument is called "suppressFinishActions". If set to true then the onSelectionChanged function will not get called.

Comment: Since version v30, rowNode.setSelected() property `suppressFinishActions` has been removed, please use `gridApi.setNodesSelected()` for bulk actions, and the event `source` property for ignoring events instead.

Answer (score 0):

There still (April 2022) doesn't seem to be a good solution to this in the AG Grid API.

One work-around/hack may be to capture a timestamp in the code that selects rows and make the selection event handler depend on this. Like so:

```
// individual row selections above
const updated = Date.now();

this.gridOptions.onSelectionChanged = event => {      
    if (Date.now() - updated < 200) {
        return; 
    }
    // complex event handler below
        ...
```